# Send info between tabs (EditText to a TextView)

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, tabs, android-edittext

Hi all I´m triying to do something i feel really simple but I´m very stack with.

There are 2 fragments divide with tabs. One has a button and 2 editText, and the otherone has a text view where I want to show the modifications. My problem is that it crash once I click in the button and I don´t know why.

I hope you can help me guys, and I´m sorry if there is something wrong on my procedure.

Here the code Java with the edittext + button:

```
EditText tituloET, lugarET;
TextView tituloTV, lugarTV;
Button asignarTL;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titulo_fragment, container, false);

    tituloET = view.findViewById(R.id.tituloET);
    lugarET = view.findViewById(R.id.lugarET);
    tituloTV = view.findViewById(R.id.tituloTV);
    lugarTV = view.findViewById(R.id.lugarTV);
    asignarTL = view.findViewById(R.id.asignarTL);

    asignarTL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (tituloTV.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                tituloTV.setText("Titulo del evento: " + tituloET.getText().toString());
            } else {
                tituloTV.setText("");
            }

            if (lugarTV.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                lugarTV.setText("Lugar del evento: " + lugarET.getText().toString());
            } else {
                lugarTV.setText("");
            }
        }
    });


    return view;

}
```

Now the one with TextView, as you can see there is a map already in it, this part is all working, my only problem is that crash once I press the button:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.evento_fragment, container, false);
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (mapFragment == null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        mapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        ft.replace(R.id.map, mapFragment).commit();
    }
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: > My problem is that it crash once I click in the button and I don´t know why.
When you have a crash. you should post the stack trace as part of your question.
Also post the full definition of your classes so we can see which class is which and where things are defined.

Answer (score 0):

> There are 2 fragments divide with tabs. One has a button and 2 editText, and the otherone has a text view where I want to show the modifications.

You say you have *two* fragments, one with EditTexts and one with TextViews.

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titulo_fragment, container, false);

    tituloET = view.findViewById(R.id.tituloET);
    lugarET = view.findViewById(R.id.lugarET);
    tituloTV = view.findViewById(R.id.tituloTV);
    lugarTV = view.findViewById(R.id.lugarTV);
    asignarTL = view.findViewById(R.id.asignarTL);
```

Your code says you're trying to access EditTexts and TextViews in *one* fragment.

---

You need to pass the data from one fragment to the other, not try to access all the views within one Fragment.

Please read the documentation on communicating with Fragments.

https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate